# How best to pass a python dictionary to PHP using file IO

Tags: php, python

I have a python script running on a cron job, once a minute, which builds some data into a dictionary. I am writing that data into a simple, space separated, text file and reading that into PHP whenever the webpage is requested.

What is correct way to do pass this information? What I am doing now certainly feels clunky since I am rebuilding essentially the same structure in PHP. How do I just write my python dictionary (perhaps an order dictionary is needed) to disk so that PHP can read it directly into a PHP array?

I also worry a bit about whether this method of transfer is kinda archaic. Should I be using a database instead, e.g. SQLlite? I worry that someone will load the page as the file is being updated which might cause some problems.

I just need something light and simple. Don't want to overcomplicate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's how someone else did it: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/252

Comment: A space-CSV file is as good as a JSON dump. But it depends on which sort of data you have. Is it a global configuration thingy, or do you actually have spool directory of sorts? Is it really just a single list of something, or would it benefit from the relational model of a database? (And e.g. could it be used for querying against other database tables?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any language can read JSON, as JSON is simply a way to format data as text, which can easily be parsed by any program. To write the dictionary as a json file, you do this:

```
import json
myfile = open('data.json','w+')

#create your dict

json.dump(mydict,myfile)
myfile.close()
```

now to read it in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
```

Comment: Great thanks guys. I will try the JSON method of passing the data. One question though. What about ordering? If I don't use an ordered dict, won't the order end up random in PHP? I don't want that so I guess I either have to use an ordered dict or sort them in PHP, right?

Comment: If you want a specific order, you'll indeed need some ordered dict implementation in python, as the order in a standard python dict is an implementation detail. The collections module in python 2.7 has an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Actually, I think I am fine. I actually have an array of dictionaries. All I care about is that the array order is preserved which is must be.

Comment: that's true indeed, because the order of the array is determined by the indexes of the elements, whereas in a dict, it depends on the hashed values.

Comment: For posterity, that is missing a $ sign. $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));

Comment: edited. It's been quite some time since I've worked with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether PHP handles json data, but if so, that's probably the way to go. See the `json` module [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) for more...

And in fact, PHP does handle json data: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

This should be a relatively simple but robust way to transfer the data.

Comment: PHP has multiple ways of reading JSON. Make your cron job write to a file like `output.json.tmp` and then move the file to `output.json` once it is finished writing. This will ensure `output.json` is always a complete file.

Comment: Will PHP ever throw an error if it is trying to read that file in the few milliseconds I am moving the temp file to the real one? Or will it just wait and try again?